# Catching exception and handling in except: if-statement

Tags: python, flask

I have 2 possible errors that I could get in my use case: `'RSA key format is not supported'` for incorrect passphrase and `'PEM encryption format not supported.'` for required passphrase but none given. These are both ValueError type.

I'm trying to do this in try-except

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, request, json, jsonify
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/key2pub', methods = ['POST'])
def api_keypub():
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':

        resp = None
        try:
            pubkey = RSA.importKey(request.json['key'], request.json['passphrase'])
        except ValueError as e:
            if e == 'RSA key format is not supported':
                global resp
                resp = jsonify({"error": "Incorrect passphrase", "raw": e})
            elif e == 'PEM encryption format not supported.':
                global resp
                resp = jsonify({"error": "Passphrase missing", "raw": e})

        return resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True);
```

I'm getting the error:

```
...
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

So it seems that `resp` is not getting set in the except if statement.

I suspect I'm using try-except in the wrong manner, can someone show me the correct way to do this?

Comment: your if else statement isn't inside your except statement. If that's a typo then print `e` and make sure it is returning the right string

Comment: Yes, that was a typo on SO, it is correctly indented in my code.

Comment: what would be returned in case that the content type is not `application/json` ?

Comment: What do you respond in the case where there are no exceptions? It looks like your "normal" case is no response, which matches the error you are reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write to a `global resp` while you actually have a local one. So the `global resp` will be set, but your local `resp` which is set to `None` will not be changed, therefore you will return `None`. So if you remove the `global resp` declaration should it work correctly. Maybe also set a default resp in case its another error which you would miss. So something like the following

```
    resp = None
    try:
        pubkey = RSA.importKey(request.json['key'], request.json['passphrase'])
    except ValueError as e:
        if str(e) == 'RSA key format is not supported':
            resp = jsonify({"error": "Incorrect passphrase", "raw": str(e)})
        elif str(e) == 'PEM encryption format not supported.':
            resp = jsonify({"error": "Passphrase missing", "raw": str(e)})
        else:
            resp = jsonify({"error": "Unexpected error", "raw": str(e)})

    return resp
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the global scope. I needed that. I also had to cast `e` to string with `str(e)`.

Comment: missing str() at `if e...`. I can't edit less than 4 chars

Answer (score -1):

api_keypub is your innermost context here: resp is local to that context.  Using **global** isn't going to help.

On top of that, you need to indent your **if** statement to be part of the **except** clause.